# Automatically fixing python indentations

Tags: python, auto-indent, autopep8

I have code without correct indentations

```
if age > 18: 
if salary > 100000: 
print('success') 
elif salary < 50000: 
print('fail') 
else: 
print('get_more_info')
else: 
print('fail')
```

I need to get

```
if age > 18: 
    if salary > 100000: 
        print('success') 
    elif salary < 50000: 
        print('fail') 
    else: 
        print('get_more_info')
else: 
    print('fail')
```

I try to use

```
exec(autopep8.fix_code(str))
```

but I get an error

```
File "<string>", line 3
print('success') elif salary < 50000: print('fail') else: print('get_more_info') else: print('fail')
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also I try to use `reindent.py`
But it return

```
  File "code_file.py", line 1
if age > 18: if salary > 100000: print('success') elif salary < 50000:     print('fail') else: print('get_more_info') else: print('fail')
                                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I fix that and do it automatically?

Comment: You can't in general, because unindented Python code is ambiguous.  But a more basic question: why do you have unindented Python in the first place?

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple correct ways to indent the code? Should it output a random correctly indented program? Or should it throw an error?

Comment: Also, what if there's a way to indent the program that's syntactically correct but semantically incorrect?

Comment: @Aran-Fey best way to get an error in this case

Comment: @Aran-Fey if there are some semantic errors, it returns error. I try to write dsl with python and generate python code from some expressions, not python. So I try to add there correct indentations

Comment: This isn't all that important given that what you're doing isn;t going to work, but… the reason you're getting a `SyntaxError` from `autopep8` and `reindent` is that you don't actually have what you say you have; there aren't even any newlines in what you're passing it. Maybe that's just because you did something silly to build `str`, like strip off all the newlines and then join all the lines together? Or maybe you have `\r`-style newlines instead or `\n` or `\r\n`? I don't know.

Comment: Also, the example string you passed to `autopep8` doesn't match the example here—and there is no way to indent that code properly in the first place, since it has two `else` clauses and only one `if`/`for`/`while`/`try` to attach to.

Comment: @abarnert it's my fault. I've fixed that and add correct string.

Comment: The corrected version seems to be missing some of the newlines but not others, which is probably even harder to repair than one missing all newlines—unless the missing newlines actually have some pattern you can exploit in some way.